# Understanding the structure of a PromQL Aggregation?

Tags: prometheus

I'm new to Prometheus, I'm trying to understand the syntactic rules of a PromQL query.  From the docs, it states `<aggr-op>([parameter,] <vector expression>) [without|by (<label list>)]`, which makes sense given the examples they show.

However from the Robust Perception blog he shows some queries like `sum without (cpu)(rate(node_cpu[1m]))`, and internally there's a query to scan all jobs with a healthy metric `count by (job) (up)`

What I'm trying to understand here is is seems that passing in a parameter or vector expression into an aggregator is optional - and if it is, what is queried when you omit the vector expression?

It appears both `count(up) by (job)` and `count by (job) (up)` are similar and possibly equivalent?  Is this format an artifact of the Go programming language, or just undocumented flexibility in the query language?

Answer (score 1):

> What I'm trying to understand here is is seems that passing in a parameter or vector expression into an aggregator is optional - and if it is, what is queried when you omit the vector expression?

If you don't pass an explicit by/without clause it's the same as `by()`.

> Is this format an artifact of the Go programming language, or just undocumented flexibility in the query language?

Both are supported, and there is debate as to which to use. I recommend having your by/without in front, as it's much easier to read non-trivial expressions.

Comment: I think that should be "the same as `by()`" instead of "the same as `without()`".

Comment: Right you are, fixed.